# How do I solve this 'UnpicklingError' in my deep learning model

Tags: python, heroku, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, fast-ai

I have been trying to deploy my model output to Heroku server and I am having slug size issues. So I decided to upload the model to google drive and load it as per [instructions](https://course.fast.ai/deployment_heroku)

Instructions:

```
import urllib.request

MODEL_URL = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=YOUR_FILE_ID"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(MODEL_URL, "model.pkl")

learner = load_learner(Path("."), "model.pkl")
```

And I had this error when I tried to load my model:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnpicklingError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-ed3e7516de3e> in <module>()
----> 1 learn_inf = load_learner(path/'model.pkl')

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/serialization.py in _legacy_load(f, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
    918             "functionality.")
    919 
--> 920     magic_number = pickle_module.load(f, **pickle_load_args)
    921     if magic_number != MAGIC_NUMBER:
    922         raise RuntimeError("Invalid magic number; corrupt file?")

UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '<'.
```

Also see the image for more.

Please how can I resolve this issue? Could the way my model is being downloaded be affecting it too?

[image]

Comment: In general, you don't want to pickle your deep learning models. There are downsides to pickling. Use `savemodel` instead. In case you pickle, make sure to save as binary.